# my usb wifi adapter isnt working Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, adapter

hi i recently purchased a USB WIFI adapter but when i plugged it into my computer and went to settings no WIFI adapters were found. I opened a terminal and ran lsusb to make sure it detected the USB and it did and it showed up as:

Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter

So i do not have the appropriate drivers?
I opened additional drivers to see if it recommended any drivers but it did not.
If anyone could help me install the appropriate drivers or do something else to make my adapter work, that would be much appreciated it would be a shame to throw away a perfectly good WIFI adapter.

Some additional information: i checked the sellers website for linux support and it says it does support linux a link to the website here: https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/p/wifi-adapter-usb-1200mbps-5ghz-dual-antenne/9300000032584164/?bltgh=s4z0fJn7cCu5FT5hBstNzA.2_36.37.ProductImage

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Try this repo [link](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_26334.20180126_COEX20171012-5044)

Hope It will work..!

Comment: hi Vashishth Patel i downloaded and unzipped the github file you recommended me and i followed the DMKS installation unfortunately 'cd rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_25643.20171212_COEX20171012-5044' resulted in a directory not found i tried opening the extracted file in a terminal and continued with the other steps in the DMKS installation but this also did not work the entire output of the terminal is too long to put in this comment

Comment: 1. Download  https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/archive/5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a.zip
 2. `cd path/to/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a`
 3. `sudo chmod +x build.sh`
 4. `bash build.sh`                 Try this one...

Comment: i downloaded and extracted your file at step 1 but at step two the output remains $ cd path/to/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a 
bash: cd: path/to/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry i made mistake in comment... Please do as follow...........                            
1. Download and unzip this repo. https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/archive/5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a.zip  
    2. cd rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a
    3. sudo chmod +x build.sh
    4 . bash build.sh                             it works for me...!

Comment: the cd did work this time but when i followed with sudo chmod +x build.sh 4 . bash build.sh it outputs chmod: cannot access '4': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'bash': No such file or directory